# How to open menu from bottom like Google Photos in Ionic 7

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I have a requirement to open the menu based on gesture from bottom as shown in below image GIF.

[image]

Here is what I'm able to achieve: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/g3jth8?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FExample.vue)

```js
<template>
  <ion-menu content-id="main-content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu Content</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-button>Click to close the menu</ion-button>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-page id="main-content">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content class="ion-padding">
      <ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-button>Click to open the menu</ion-button>
      </ion-menu-toggle>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-page>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import { IonButton, IonContent, IonHeader, IonMenu, IonMenuToggle, IonPage, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/vue';
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  export default defineComponent({
    components: {
      IonButton,
      IonContent,
      IonHeader,
      IonMenu,
      IonMenuToggle,
      IonPage,
      IonTitle,
      IonToolbar,
    },
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please note the addition of phrases "Hi", "please help me", and "thanks in advance" will attract downvotes. Stack Overflow is not a chatroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ionic sheet modal [Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#sheet-modal):

```
<template>
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>App</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content class="ion-padding">
    <ion-button id="open-modal" expand="block">Open Sheet Modal</ion-button>

    <ion-modal ref="modal" trigger="open-modal" :initial-breakpoint="0.25" :breakpoints="[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75]">
      <ion-content class="ion-padding">
        <ion-searchbar @click="$refs.modal.$el.setCurrentBreakpoint(0.75)" placeholder="Search"></ion-searchbar>
        <ion-list>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
              <ion-img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=b"></ion-img>
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label>
              <h2>Connor Smith</h2>
              <p>Sales Rep</p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
              <ion-img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=a"></ion-img>
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label>
              <h2>Daniel Smith</h2>
              <p>Product Designer</p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
              <ion-img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=d"></ion-img>
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label>
              <h2>Greg Smith</h2>
              <p>Director of Operations</p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-avatar slot="start">
              <ion-img src="https://i.pravatar.cc/300?u=e"></ion-img>
            </ion-avatar>
            <ion-label>
              <h2>Zoey Smith</h2>
              <p>CEO</p>
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-modal>
  </ion-content>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
  import {
    IonButton,
    IonModal,
    IonHeader,
    IonContent,
    IonToolbar,
    IonTitle,
    IonItem,
    IonList,
    IonAvatar,
    IonImg,
    IonLabel,
    IonSearchbar,
  } from '@ionic/vue';
</script>
```

Comment: This solves my problem . but how to implement that swipe up ?

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: Swipe up and opening of the  sheet-modal just as shown in question GIF

Comment: for that you can use ionic gestures to capture swipe up:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/gestures